# Razor Client Library page callback to parent Blazor Server page

Tags: url, razor, hyperlink, blazor, lib

I have built a Blazor server app which utilises a Razor Class Library to host razor pages. The app works perfectly when I call any razor page in the RCL from the NavMenu in the Blazor Server app.
However, I'm trying to figure out how to return to a page in the Blazor Server app from a link in the RCL Razor page or Controller.
Could anyone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass a return url to a page, so that you can navigate back to the "return url" at some point?

Comment: Can you modify the source of the RCL? If yes, create an event in the component and listen to the event on the server app. When the event is triggered, use NavigationManager.NavigateTo(*url*) to navigate to the *url*

Comment: Many thanks for the comments.  I can modify the source of the RCL so I have been investigating how to create an event in the RCL and listen to the event on the server app.  I must admit I am on the learning curve with Razor and Blazor so I'm having difficulty understanding how to do this.  Does anybody have an example of raising an event from either the _Layout page or the controller in the RCL back to the Blazor Server app and how it can be handled in the Blazor server app.  Many thanks.